# Weird outputs in file

Tags: c++, file-io

```
int main()
{
ofstream outCredit( "credit.txt" , ios::out | ios::binary ) ;

if( !outCredit )
{
    cerr << "File could not open file " << endl ;
    exit(1) ;
}

ClientData blankClient ;

for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i )
    outCredit.write( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( &blankClient ), sizeof( ClientData ) )  ;
}
```

I have declared a ClientData class with members namely `int account , char firstName[15] , char lastName[10] , double account` ?
When the file is created , which should contain 100 empty records , I am getting something like this in the entire file 100 times , what is wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: What you expect for value of `a` if I declare just `int a;` ?
garbage right ? Same is case with uninitialized `blankClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write out structs and classes in this way. You must individually write/stream out each element you want in the file.

Comment: I want to create a Random-access file , so that any new account can be added without disturbing the old one , and I am allocating the required number of bytes for each record

Comment: @digi_abhshk Structs and classes may contain padding between members, which is probably why you see the random characters. Also the layout in memory depends on the compiler, so a file written with code compiled by one compiler may be incompatible with code compiled by another compiler.

Comment: @digi_abhshk You can still do that when outputting each member yourself.

Comment: that is why I am getting a total of 40 bytes allocated for each struct when there should be actually 37

Comment: what is the way out , here ?

Comment: @digi_abhshk you can write each member to the stream individually. So long as they are basic data types and arrays of basic data, that will be fine. Put it into a writeout function in your class to keep it tidy. You read back in the same way (read each member in order)

Comment: @digi_abhshk you may want to look into a library to access xml/database files.

Comment: @NeilKirk _"You cannot write out structs and classes in this way"_ pardon ?

Comment: @P0W You cannot take a pointer to the beginning of a struct and binary dump the memory to a file. Well you can, but it often results in problems..

Comment: @NeilKirk OP is just writing same uninitialized record `bankClient` 100 times and the output is nothing _unexpected_

Comment: @P0W I assumed blankClient has a default constructor that initializes the fields to 0. Maybe the garbage is from uninitialized members but my point is still valid (there may be padding which is garbage even if you initialize members)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample program that writes object to the file and reads the same.

```
 //Objfile.h
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#define STRLEN 10
class A
{
   public:
     int a;
     float c;
     char *f;
     A():a(10),c(30.5){ 
        f=new char[STRLEN]; 
        memset(f, '\0', STRLEN); 
        strcpy(f,"fed"); 
        std::cout<<"\n A"; 
    }
    ~A() { delete[] f; }
    void print() { std::cout<<" a:"<<a<<" g:"<<g<<" f:"<<f; }

 };

 //ObjFile.cpp  // Writes Object to the file
 #include<objfile.h>
 main() 
 {
    std::ofstream out("obj.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
    if (!out) {
       std::cout<<"\n Error in opening output file out.txt";
       return 0;
    }
    A a;
    out.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
    out.close();
  }

  //ObjfileRead.cpp    //Reads record (Object) from the file and prints
  #include<objfile.h>
  main()
  {
    std::ifstream in("obj.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    if (!in) {
       std::cout<<"in file can't open \" obj.txt \" ";
       return 0;
    }
    A *b;
    char *temp_obj=new char[sizeof(A)];
    in.read(temp_obj,sizeof(A));
    b=reinterpret_cast<A*>(temp_obj);
    b->print();
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```